# Green Rectangle in Microsoft Teams when sharing screen

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-teams

I am using Microsoft Teams (version 1.2.00.34161) on Windows 10 (Enterprise v1709). When another teams user offers to share his screen, I click the accept, but instead of the screen appearing on my display I get a solid green rectangle.

Does anyone know what is causing this and how to fix it?

**Edit** I've just finished re-installing Teams but the problem remains.

Comment: If you hover over it, is there a tooltip?

Comment: @spikey_richie, no, there is no tooltip. But on taking control, I can move the mouse pointer around on the other screen.

Comment: _This likely doesn't apply, but just in case_: the only time I've ever encountered green borders _(granted not with a solid fill)_ is when the application has been sandboxed via a 3rd party sandbox feature.

Comment: @JW0914, thanks for the tip, but so far as I know I don't have anything like that involved.

Comment: Since Teams is a commercial product, you should contact Microsoft support.